# How to use output file in another powershell command?

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, mp4box

I'm using auto-editor first to cut out motionless parts, then Mp4Box to add my intro.

I can't figure out how to automatically use the output from auto-editor into Mp4Box.

This is what I have so far.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 | ForEach -Process {mp4box -add c:\intro.mp4 -cat $_ -new $a($_.BaseName + '.mp4') -force-cat && del $_ && auto-editor $a --edit_based_on motion --motion_threshold 0.000001% --no_open}
```

I tried adding $a to make the output into a variable but that doesn't work. I have the script reversed for testing purposes as Mp4Box is a lot faster than auto-editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the variable `$a` on a separate statement, before calling any of the commands that uses it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 | ForEach {
     $a = $_.BaseName + '.mp4'
     mp4box -add c:\intro.mp4 -cat $_ -new $a -force-cat && 
     del $_ &&
     auto-editor $a --edit_based_on motion --motion_threshold 0.000001% --no_open
}
```

I've also added some line breaks to make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you! I had to change it to delete the source file at the end and it works perfectly now.